resource.data not accessible - cloud firestore rules
I keep getting and unknown error while tesing my cloud firestore rules, even though i know it should work. After several test, i reduce the problem to not being able to access the fields of my resource and i don't know why.
Rule:

example of custom token that i would send
.
here is what a conversation looks like

does someone have any idea as why resource.data is not accessible ?
I tried to test each function indiviually, try with hardcoded values, and minimal rules, but the error only appear when i try to use resource.data.

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
